# Umbraco AD integration for an intranet

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Im wanting to build an intranet that will use Domain (AD) authentication and let the user not have to login.  So Ive been looking at the AD package **[here](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/umbraco-active-directory-authentication/)** and digging into the details a bit, it seems you have to configure a user & password in the web.config.  Then I seen [**this**](http://blog.dampee.be/post/2014/02/12/Umbraco-Backoffice-integration-with-Active-Directory.aspx#disqus_thread) example, which is seems to simply be using the AD membership provider and isnt putting any hard-coded username and password in the config file.  Are those two approaches even talking about the same thing?

I just need simple pass-through authentication based on the identity of the user passed in from the browser.  The question also comes up as to under which context will requests be made when the user uploads a file, edits content etc.  Will it be Network Service or the passed in identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have specified umbraco 7 in your question, I think you are much better of pursuing the option in your second link.

The first link was written for Umbraco 4.11, and an awful lot has changed since then. Can't tell you if the second link will simply work out-of-the-box, but imo, you have a better chance of being successful.